# three js multiple scenes (gltf)

Tags: javascript, three.js

so i have this code

```
//Variables for setup

let container;
let camera;
let renderer;
let scene;
let mutant;

function init() {
  container = document.querySelector(".scene");

  //Create scene
  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const fov = 935;
  const aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 9500;

  //Camera setup
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, -80, 120);

  const ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 2);
  scene.add(ambient);

  const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 2);
  light.position.set(50, 50, 120);
  scene.add(light);
  //Renderer
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
  renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);

  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  //Load Model
  let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load("mutant/scene.gltf", function(gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    mutant = gltf.scene.children[0];
    animate();
  });
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  mutant.rotation.y = 160.3;
  // mutant.rotation.z = 6;
  mutant.rotation.z += 0.01;
  mutant.rotation.x = -1.70;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

init();

function onWindowResize() {
  camera.aspect = container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
}

window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
```

that loads a 3d model into a website however i want to add multiple scenes so like it loads
`mutant/scene.gltf` **and** `golem/scene.gltf` for example, two models or more how do i do that?
i tried adding another div with class scene and like copying all the files again with names like instead of app.js app2.js etc. didn't work sadly assistance would be highly appreciated

index code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="scene"></div>
    <script src="./three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to create a separate scene when importing a second model. You can reuse the entire setup, even the loader instance. Try it like so:

```js
const manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
manager.onLoad = () => animate();

const loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader(manager);

loader.load("mutant/scene.gltf", function(gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    mutant = gltf.scene.children[0];
});

loader.load("golem/scene.gltf", function(gltf) {
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    golem = gltf.scene.children[0];
});
```

You just have to make sure to position both assets properly. With the above code, they are placed at the same spot.

Comment: thank you! the code works now, but may i ask how do i  set the second camera and position?

Comment: Um, not sure what you mean by that. You only have a single camera in your scene.

Comment: how do i change the position and fov, far, and near of the second model though? it's set on the fist models position fov far an near, which makes it smaller because its a different model

Comment: Sorry, but that does not make sense. `fov`, `near`,  and `far` are camera properties. You can only change the position, rotation and scale of your models. So try it with `golem.position.set( 1, 2, 3 );` and/or `golem.scale.set( 2, 2, 2 );`.